# What was the first work of fiction about flying machines?

Tags: history-of-literature, jules-verne

There are two stories by Jules Verne which I know about which captured the public imagination about Flying Machines in the 18th century. The first is the somewhat unknown *A Trip Round the World in a Flying Machine* ([archive.org](https://archive.org/details/triproundworldin00vern)) and the more famous *Around the World in 80 Days*. By flying machine, I mean some sort of mechanical or semi-mechanical machine or construct. It doesn't and didn't need to be similar to the way aircraft are today. In fact, the wilder the shapes or ideas were and are. The better.

As I shared in the comments, in 1493 Leonardo Da Vinci did share lot of sketches about flying machines, wouldn't that have lead to a spate of stories in that time.

What was the first story which penned and shared about flying machines before Jules Verne, or was Jules Verne the first? And if somebody knows of any subsequent stories that would be a bonus too :)

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! As of right now I think this question is off-topic as an [open-ended list](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1561/). Two ways to save it would be to ask instead for the first work of fiction about a flying machine (thus making it a [[tag:history-of-literature]] question) or about Jules Verne's inspiration for his works about flying machines (thus making it an [[tag:inspiration]] question). Would either work for you?

Comment: Have edited and put it the way you asked. You somehow got to the meat of my question. Anyways, thank you. Hope you have a fine day :)

Comment: Thanks for editing! Interesting question, I hope someone will be able to answer it :-)

Comment: What are the requirements to be a "flying machine"? For example, do the wings made by [Daedalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daedalus#Icarus) in Greek legend count? How about magic carpets? A [mythological flying palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimana)? (All examples pulled from [Wikipedia's article on flying machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_flying_machines))

Comment: The idea would be fantasy but perhaps with mechanical wings or something. Although wouldn't Daedalus count more as of mythology than fantasy. From what I know, Icarus claim to fame was that he flew too close to the sun. That's the breath of my greek mythology knowledge :)

Comment: If I were to look back, then my understanding or imagination would perhaps have been triggered when the first steam engine was made, 82 BCE . https://www.imeche.org/about-us/imeche-engineering-history/mechanical-engineering-history-timeline

Comment: Apparently, the first human flight happened right after that, in 1010, didn't take much long for the first hang-glider.

Comment: Also Leonardo Da Vinci 100 odd sketches of flying machines in 1493 would put it right there. I am sure there were a lot of stories around that time as well.

Comment: It has been some years since I read *Around the World in 80 Days* but I recall no flying machine. Trains, steamships, horses, and foot travel, yes. but no flight. IIRC part of the point was that the schedule was in fact just barely possible in the real world (if all went well) when JV published this. And indeed a newspaper reporter, Nelly Bly, carried out such a trip shortly after the novel was published.  So no airplains need or wanted.

Comment: But the is the early *Five Weeks in a Balloon* Verene's first novel, and the late *Master of the World*

Comment: "Although wouldn't Daedalus count more as of mythology than fantasy." This is irrelevant; mythology counts as fiction. It would be more helpful if you edited your answer to clarify what you mean by "flying **machine**".

Comment: You want to read Marjorie Hope Nicolson's [Voyages to the Moon](https://www.amazon.com/Voyages-Moon-Marjorie-Hope-Nicolson/dp/B0000CKMO8) for an exhaustive treatment of this question.

Comment: Depending upon your view of such things - The Bible,  Book of Ezekiel.  Alternatively the Vedic stories of Vimanas.

Comment: @DavidSiegel would be nice if you elaborate on both the stories as answers. I am sure there may be much that may interest me as well as others, thank you.

Comment: @shirish I have in the past on the SFF stack been criticized for postign answers to "first" questions about works later than ones already discussed in answers. Besides another answer has alrwady discussed *Five Weeks* under its original title of *Cinq Semaines en ballon* *Master of the World*  was one of Verne's last few novels, it involved a dirigible airship, IIRC. I read it more than 40 years ago, and forget many details. The Wikipedia plot outline for *80 days* mentions rail, steamship, foot, horse, and elephant-back travel, but no air travel. I concur.

Comment: @Tsundoku clarified it a bit more so you know what I meant, thank you.

Comment: @kimchilover saw it, was pretty informative, thank you for sharing that link :)

Answer (score 3):

[Cyrano de Bergerac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac) (1619–1655) wrote the books *L'Autre Monde: ou les États et Empires de la Lune* (*Comical History of the States and Empires of the Moon*) and *Les États et Empires du Soleil* (*The States and Empires of the Sun*) both published after his death. These contain various flying machines that convey him to the Moon and the Sun.

In the first of these, he builds a flying machine with wings. It doesn't work, but when some soldiers find it and attach fireworks to it, it actually works and carries him aloft. From [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46547/46547-h/46547-h.htm#bergerac004b)

> I had made a Machine which I fancied might carry me up as high as I pleased, so that nothing seeming to be wanting to it, I placed my self within, and from the Top of a Rock threw my self in the Air: But because I had not taken my measures aright, I fell with a sosh in the Valley below.
>
> Bruised as I was, however, I returned to my Chamber without loosing courage, and with Beef-Marrow I anointed my Body, for I was all over mortified from Head to Foot: Then having taken a dram of Cordial Waters to strengthen my Heart, I went back to look for my Machine; but I could not find it, for some Soldiers, that had been sent into the Forest to cut wood for a Bonnefire, meeting with it by chance, had carried it with them to the Fort: Where after a great deal of guessing what it might be, when they had discovered the invention of the Spring, some said, that a good many Fire-Works should be fastened to it, because their Force carrying them up on high, and the Machine playing its large Wings, no Body but would take it for a Fiery Dragon. In the mean time I was long in search of it, but found it at length in the Market-place of Kebeck (Quebec), just as they were setting Fire to it. I was so transported with Grief, to find the Work of my Hands in so great Peril, that I ran to the Souldier that was giving Fire to it, caught hold of his Arm, pluckt the Match out of his Hand, and in great rage threw my self into my Machine, that I might undo the Fire-Works that they had stuck about it; but I came too late, for hardly were both my Feet within, when whip, away went I up in a Cloud.

Comment: Also [one of the first](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93537/31394) pieces of writing about *spaceships* (depending on exactly how one defines a spaceship).

Comment: I am curious to know whether the information about CYRANO DE BERGERAC given in Project Gutenberg is the one made by Cyrano or some other sources, as it seems to be quite funny.

Answer (score 1):

I think there were several 19th century example that precede Jules Verne, but I'm not familiar with those, so I can't name them.

That said, Jules Verne was fascinated enough with flying that flying machines appear in multiple of his stories.  *L’Île mystérieuse* (1875) contains a more realistic example: its protagonists travel on a kind of balloon that was already available at the time Jules Verne wrote the serial novel.  *Cinq Semaines en ballon* (1873) has a more fantastic example: a hydrogen balloon improved with sci-fi elements.  *Hector Servadac* (1877) also includes people traveling by balloon.  *Deux Ans de vacances* (1888) features a giant kite lifting a human using the power of wind. *Robur-le-Conquérant* (1886) is perhaps the first of Jules Verne's novels that features not only balloons, but also heavier than air aircrafts.  *De la Terre à la Lune* (1865) and its sequel features a four meter large spaceship shot with a giant cannon to space with enough speed to reach the Moon, the main fantastical element being how its payload humans survive the launch.    *Les Enfants du capitaine Grant* (1868) and *Les Indes noires* (1877) don't feature flying machines per se, only giant birds, the former powerful enough to lift a human adolescent.